# How to create a empty string list and append it by using shell script?

Tags: shell-script, shell

```
A=Book,Pen,Pencil...n

B=Cat,Rat,Bat.....m
```

Code is::

```
Type=()
TEST=`echo $path`
echo $TEST
```

Output ::

```
n/m
```

Excepted output ::

```
Book/Cat/Book/Rat/Book/Bat/..../Book/m/Pen/Cat/Pen/Rat/Pen/Bat/...../Pen/m/Pencil/Cat/Pencil/Rat/Pencil/Bat/..../Pencil/m/......./n/Cat/n/Rat/n/Bat/...../n/m
```

Comment: `path+="${i}/${j}/"` will do here, no need for an echo in a subshell.  And `echo "$path"` is sufficient. You don't need to `TEST="$(echo $path)"` .  If you need to use subshells, please use the `$()`-Notation instead of backticks.

Answer (score 1):

After you changed the requirements of your question *again*...

In `bash` you could use a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
$ printf '%s' {Book/,Pen/,Pencil/,n/}{Cat/,Rat/,Bat/,m/}
Book/Cat/Book/Rat/Book/Bat/Book/m/Pen/Cat/Pen/Rat/Pen/Bat/Pen/m/Pencil/Cat/Pencil/Rat/Pencil/Bat/Pencil/m/n/Cat/n/Rat/n/Bat/n/m/
```

Note that the output doesn't end with a newline.

To create `path` from two comma separated strings in `$A` and `$B`:

```
#!/bin/bash

A="Book,Pen,Pencil,n"
B="Cat,Rat,Bat,m"

oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
for i in $A; do
    for j in $B; do
        path+="$i/$j/"
    done
done
IFS=$oldIFS

printf '%s\n' "$path"
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh
Book/Cat/Book/Rat/Book/Bat/Book/m/Pen/Cat/Pen/Rat/Pen/Bat/Pen/m/Pencil/Cat/Pencil/Rat/Pencil/Bat/Pencil/m/n/Cat/n/Rat/n/Bat/n/m/
```

Comment: I tried to put variables between the braces, but that won't work, unless I use `eval`: `A='Basic-Call/,Call-Hold/' ; B='VoLTE-VoLTE/,VoLTE-3G/' ; eval printf '%s' {$A}{$B}`.  You wouldn't know how to use those vars directly?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way around `eval` as brace expansion is performed before any other expansion. From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html):
"The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and filename expansion."

Comment: Thanks you all for the response:) actually values of $A & $B are stored in another parameter. Hence I want to get a idea on how to create a empty string list and append it

Comment: @yashunatesh Please don't change the requirements. Added a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
#complete_robotpath=() ### not used in script ... so commented
IFS=','
A=Basic-Call,Call-Hold  ## In shell, we dont prefix with $ while declaring variable and should not have space in value.
B=VoLTE-VoLTE,VoLTE-3G
read -ra ADDR1 <<< "$A" ## In shell, we should pass value of a variable by prefixing with $
read -ra ADDR2 <<< "$B" IFS=',' ## In shell, we should pass value of a variable by prefixing with $
for i in "${ADDR1[@]}";
do
  for j in "${ADDR2[@]}";
  do
  robot_path+=`echo $i/$j/` ## "+=" to concatinate string and sufix by / as expected result
  done
done

pybot_exec_cmd=`echo $robot_path`
echo $pybot_exec_cmd
```

Output:

```
Basic-Call/VoLTE-VoLTE/Basic-Call/VoLTE-3G/Call-Hold/VoLTE-VoLTE/Call-Hold/VoLTE-3G/
```

Comment: Thank you so much for response, can you share this by creating array of strings and append it with the execution :)

Comment: can u share how the input will be?

Comment: `robot_path+="${i}/${j}/"` will do here, no need for an `echo` in a subshell.

Comment: $A= Book, Pen, Paper,Pencil.......(n times) $B= Cat, Parrot, Peacock....(n times) , I am not getting the syntax of how to create a empty stringlist and append it according to user

Comment: No leading `$` for assignements.  `A=''` gets you an empty list. `A+='Book, Pen, Paper, '` adds to that list. No spaces allowed before or after the `=`.